# How to write SQL query to LINQ using Lambda Expression?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Here is Simple SQL query...  I want to get `selected field not all table fields` by Using `Entity frame work List function`.

```
"Select CustName, CustEmail, CustAddress, CustContactNo  from Customers"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already have a context defined and table mapped.

```
var results = dbContext.Customers.Select(x => new { x.CustName, x.CustEmail, x.CustAddress, x.CustContactNo }).ToList();
```

Comment: public List<Customer> GeAllCust()
        {
               var results = db.Customers.Select(x => new { x.CustName, x.CustEmail, x.CustAddress, x.CustContactNo }).ToList();
               return results;
        }

Comment: Showing error when returns a list..."Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WebApplication2.Customer>"